# django crispy forms: form field in template

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

Is it at all possible to render a forms field independently, for example `{{form.firstname}}`. If i use `{{form|crispy}}` it renders like `{{form.as_p}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`as_crispy_field`](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_templatetags.html#templatetags.crispy_forms_filters.as_crispy_field) filter

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{{ form.field|as_crispy_field }}
```